# What does % do to strings in Python?

Tags: python, string, documentation, operators

I have failed to find documentation for the operator % as it is used on strings in Python. What does this operator do when it is used with a string on the left hand side?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's the string formatting operator. Read up on [string formatting in Python](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting).

```
format % values
```

Creates a string where `format` specifies a format and `values` are the values to be filled in.

Answer (score 10):

It applies [printf-like formatting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf) to a string, so that you can substitute certain parts of a string with values of variables.
Example

```
# assuming numFiles is an int variable
print "Found %d files" % (numFiles, )
```

See the link provided by Konrad

Answer (score 8):

Note that starting from Python 2.6, it's recommended to use the new [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method:

```
>>> "The sum of 1 + 2 is {0}".format(1+2)
'The sum of 1 + 2 is 3'
```

If you are using 2.6, you may want to keep using `%` in order to remain compatible with older versions, but in Python 3 there's no reason not to use `str.format()`.

Comment: format() is really powerful too. You can use named tags like "Hello {planet}".format(planet='earth')

Comment: what does the 0 inside the {} do? this line of code seemingly runs the same without it

Answer (score 6):

The '%' operator is used for string interpolation. Since Python 2.6 the String method "format" is used insted. For details see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/