# Problems of dividing by a negative number in python

Tags: python

I am coding this in python:

```
1 / -2
```

The result is not 0 but -1, I am confused. why is python designed this way? What's the logic behind it?

*I am using python 2.7.6*

Comment: Why would you expect 0 rather than -1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integer division & modulo operation with negative operands in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348219/integer-division-modulo-operation-with-negative-operands-in-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guido himself explains it here: http://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html.

Relevant snippet:

> there is a good mathematical reason. The integer division operation (//) and its sibling, the modulo operation (%), go together and satisfy a nice mathematical relationship:
>
> a/b = q with remainder r
>
> such that
>
> b*q + r = a and 0 <= r < b
>
> ...
>
> Consider taking a POSIX timestamp (seconds since the start of 1970) and turning it into the time of day. Since there are 24*3600 = 86400 seconds in a day, this calculation is simply t % 86400. But if we were to express times before 1970 using negative numbers, the "truncate towards zero" rule would give a meaningless result! Using the floor rule it all works out fine.