# How does floor division work in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floor

1. 5//2 = 2;
2. 5//7 = 0;
3. 5//-6 = -1;
4. 5//-2 = -3;
5. 5//-3 = -2;
6. 5/-4 =  -2;

Can someone explain the logic behind this?

Comment: http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html might help you.

Comment: similar to [Integer division & modulo operation with negative operands in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348219/integer-division-modulo-operation-with-negative-operands-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way it should:

```
5 / 2 = 2.5        (2)
5 / 7 = 0.714285   (0)
5 / -6 = −0.8333   (-1 is the integer below -0.833333)
5 / -2 = −2.5      (-3)
5 / -3 = −1.6666   (-2)
```

It's a basic floor. It divides it, and then makes it the integer below.

Answer (score 4):

This is always true, ignoring floating point issues:

```
b*(a // b) + a % b == a
```

This is also always true:

```
((b > 0) == (a % b > 0)) or (a % b == 0)
```

Finally,

```
abs(a % b) < abs(b)
```

To provide this behavior, integer division rounds towards negative infinity, rather than towards zero.

Comment: Plus one although the undisclosed mention of floating point issues is a distraction.

Comment: @Bathsheba: You can do integer division with floats, but you get floats back, which aren't precise.

Answer (score 3):

Floor division works in Python the way it's mathematically defined.

```
x // y == math.floor(x/y)
```

In other words `x // y` is the largest integer less than or equal to `x / y`

Comment: Or: `fdiv = lambda a, b: (a - a % b) / b`

Comment: @AdamSmith It certainly doesn't work that way. Compare `1 // 0.1` to `math.floor(1 / 0.1)`.

Comment: @Selcuk that appears to be just floating point inaccuracies. `1 / 0.1` is very nearly 10, so flooring it becomes 9. `math.floor(1 / 0.1)` lets the `__truediv__` operator handle the floating point weirdness which it correctly accounts for, then floors afterwards.

Comment: @Selcuk note that `1 // Decimal('0.1') == Decimal('10')`. Similarly for a decimal whose binary floating-point is precise like `0.5`: `5 // 0.5 == 10`