# Difference of two imperial lengths

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, units-of-measurement, negative-number

I have a program that takes two imperial lengths (miles, yards, feet and inches) and outputs their sum and difference. My problem is that when the difference is negative, the output is incorrect.

```
def to_inches(miles, yards, feet, inches):
    return inches + (feet * 12) + (yards * 36) + (miles * 63360)


def from_inches(inches):
    miles = inches // 63360
    inches %= 63360

    yards = inches // 36
    inches %= 36

    feet = inches // 12
    inches %= 12

    return (miles, yards, feet, inches)

units1 = [int(n) for n in input().split(' ')]
units2 = [int(n) for n in input().split(' ')]

m_sum = from_inches(to_inches(*units1) + to_inches(*units2))
m_diff = from_inches(to_inches(*units1) - to_inches(*units2))

print(' '.join(str(n) for n in m_sum))
print(' '.join(str(n) for n in m_diff))
```

Input:

```
2 850 1 7
1 930 1 4
```

Output:

```
4 21 0 11
0 1680 1 3
```

Input:

```
0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0
```

Expected output:

```
1 1 0 0
-0 1759 0 0
```

Actual output:

```
1 1 0 0
-1 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because Python handles the mod operator `%` a bit weird when it comes to negative numbers. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3883019/436282

Comment: Apparently, the same is true for the integer division operator (`//`). So I ended up using `int(math.fmod(x, y))` and `int(x / y)`. Also, I added a check to make only the first number negative if any of them are negative.