# Python3 Byte Level Bit Operations

Tags: python, byte, arrays, bit, complement

Is there a byte type in Python3? I only know there is a bytearray.

What I want is that, there is a byte `0x01`, then do the Complement Operator `~` the result will be `0xFE`, however when I do the following steps, the result is `-2` and `-2` can't be added to the bytearray.

```
>>> data=bytearray([0x01])
>>> data
bytearray(b'\x01')
>>> ~data[0]
-2
>>> data[0]=~data[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3 has 2 types dealing with bytes : the `bytes` type, which is not mutable (analogous to `str`) and the `bytearray` with is mutable. If you need to cast an integer to a byte, you simply take the 8 lower order bits with `& 0xFF`.

So your last line should be :

```
data[0] = ~ data[0] & 0xFF
```

Comment: just to emphasis, for Python 3, bitwise operators work on "int" type, not "bytes". So `a = b'\x7f'; a & 0xff` won't work, instead it should be `a=b'\x7f'[0]; a & 0xff`

Answer (score 0):

You can take `~data[0]` modulo 256 to get a correctly shifted value:

```
>>> data = bytearray([0x01])
>>> data[0] = ~data[0]%256
>>> data
bytearray(b'\xfe')
```

See [negative numbers modulo in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883004/negative-numbers-modulo-in-python) for more information on modulo operation on a negative number.

Comment: And why not simply `~data[0] & 0xFF` ? It keeps the 8 lower order bits with no problem of negative modulo ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Modulo of a negative number is well defined so why not? It's the same as `&0xFF`so nothing speaks against it :)