# Weird Outputs of Modulo Operator in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, operator-keyword, modulo

I'm working on a modular sorter in python3 and have noticed weird behavior to do with the signs of input variables when taking the mod. I intend for it to sort a value by the remainder after dividing by the cycle length.

I.e., `c = 4 / 14 = 0 r **4**", "c = 18 / 14 = 1 r **4**", and "c = 32 / 14 = 2 r **4**`

All of these are 4th position values because they leave 4. However, if any of the input variables are negative, the result is not what I intend. Any ideas as to how this works (I might use this weird functionality in later coding)?

```
a = 4     #the value for sorting
b = 14    #the length of the cycle before it reaches the 0 position

def modS(val, cyc):
    c = val % cyc
    print(c)

modS(a, b)
```

E.g.,

```
a = 4
b = 14
```

prints `4`

```
a = -4
b = 14
```

prints `10`

```
a = 4
b = -14
```

prints `-10`

```
a = -4
b = -14
```

prints `-4`

These printed values might be useful for stuff like pH calculations, but not for my purposes.

Comment: So Python behaves just like it is described in the documentation? Outrageous. What is your question here?

Comment: I was wondering how this worked and how to correct the output to give the position as an absolute value along the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet to specify, so I'll try to answer what I think you're trying to ask

## Trying to get the answer you want even when it's negative

I'd recommend using [the abs() method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/number_abs.htm) to treat all the numbers as positive, e.g.,

```
def modS(val, cyc):
    c = abs(val) % abs(cyc)
    print(c)
```

which gives 4 for your data set.

Otherwise, if you're just interested to know *why* it happens, I recommend reading [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883004/the-modulo-operation-on-negative-numbers-in-python) about the same thing.

Comment: Cool. Do you know any other uses for the normal mod output?

Comment: The most popular example would be [RSA encryption](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_algorithm), but for day to day use, sometimes we need to know what the remainder of an integer division would be.