# Convert a shifted ASCII value to char inside the abc scope

Tags: python, ascii, modulo

#### Background

This question is inspired by The Caesar Cipher. Given a modified ASCII value `i` where `i > 122 or i < 97`, the goal is to find the char represented by its value. For example, since `'z'` value is `122`, then `123` references `'a'`, as well as `149` and `97 +- 26n`.

#### Goal

The function `calc_chr` should calculate shifted ASCII values while staying inside the scope of the `abc`, i.e. `[97, 122]` decimal.

#### Clear Example

let `'x'` be `120`
let `new_val` be `'x' + 5`  `-->125`
`calc_chr(new_val)` is equal to `'c'`

The function returns `'c'`, as a result of shifting `'x'`  5 times: `x -> y, z, a, b, c`.

#### Workaround

The workaround isn't efficient.

```
while new_val > 122:
    new_val -= 26
while new_val < 97:
    new_val += 26
```

The desired solution, if exists, is a calculation (not a loop).

Comment: What about `range(97,123)` ?

Comment: Its not clear what you mean by 'search numbers between'. Do you want `str((123 % 122) + 97)`

Comment: could you add more explanations for desired outputs? so, you want 123 to turn into 98, what about 246?

Comment: It’s not clear what you need.

Comment: This question was updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the following ASCII mapping:

```
                            a-z
0-18, 19-44, 45-70, 71-96, 97-122, 123-148, 149-174, 175-200, 201-226, 227-252, 253-255
h-z    a-z    a-z    a-z    a-z      a-z      a-z      a-z      a-z      a-z      a-c

\--------- 1 -------------------/
                           \---------------------------- 2 ---------------------------/
```

For most programming languages (where the sign of the remainder is the sign of the dividend), two different formulas could be used:

1. For all numbers in the range 0 to 122 use:

   ```
    r = 122 - ((122 - n) % 26)
   ```
2. For all numbers in the range 97 to 255 use:

   ```
    r = ((n - 97) % 26) + 97
   ```

However, because the remainder does not change if we add a multiple of the divider to the dividend, we can add 4 times 26 and avoid having to deal with a negative dividend altogether.

```
    r = ((n - 97) % 26) + 97
 => r = ((n - 97 + (4 * 26)) % 26) + 97
<=> r = ((n - 97 + 104) % 26) + 97
<=> r = ((n + 7) % 26) + 97       ; This will work no matter how '%' functions
```

Now in Python, because of [how the `%` operator functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883004/the-modulo-operation-on-negative-numbers-in-python), we can get by with this one formule:

```
r = ((n - 97) % 26) + 97
```

---

A **very fast** alternative defines a 256-byte array and then uses the calculated number as an offset in this array, fetching the result at once.

Below is what it could look like in assembly (MASM):

```
; On input AL register is number n=[0,255]
mov bx, offset array
xlatb
; On output AL register is number r=[97,122]         ; ["a","z"]

...

array db 'hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
      db 9 dup ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
      db 'abc'
```

And in Python it becomes

```
s[n]
```

with *n* ranging from 0 to 255 and using a 256-byte string *s*

```
s = ("hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
     "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
     "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
     "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
     "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
     "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
     "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
     "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
     "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
     "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
     "abc"
    )
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason `r = ((n - 97) % 26) + 97` for `n=95` returns `y`, which is correct. Am I missing something? How a negative `mod` works?

Comment: You're not supposed to use that formula for `n=95`. That's a value for which you need to use the other formula `r = 122 - ((122 - n) % 26)`. Normally -2 % 26 would have to return -2, the remainder from dividing by 26.

Comment: Yet in python `(-2) % 26` returns `24` for some reason.

Comment: Apparently Python chooses to do things differently than most other programming languages! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883004/the-modulo-operation-on-negative-numbers-in-python. To be honest, I did not see that the question was tagged [tag:python]...

Answer (score 4):

It's not really clear what you actually want to do. My understanding is you want to type in an artificial number and then have it transformed into the from 97 to 122 (both included in the interval).

Easiest way would be:

```
number = input('Your number: ')
mod_number = ((number - 97) % 26) + 97
print(number, chr(number))
```

That way you type in a number, if it is between 97 and 122 included, then it will be kept. Otherwise it will be moved into that interval. So if you type in 123 you will end up with 97 and if you hand over 96 you will end up with 122.