# In Python, whats the logic behind %

Tags: python

For example why `2 %-8` results in -6?

I was reading [What is the result of % in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/what-is-the-result-of-in-python) nut I didn't manage to get it, for example I read in comments exaplanation of

`7%2` its `7-2=5` and then `5-2` = `3` and then `3-2` = `1` and so thats the result, but can't manage to apply that to

`2 - (-8) = 10 - (-8) = 18`, can someone explain? and whats the criteria to stop? thanks :)

Comment: `2 %-8` has a negative result because it follows the sign of the right modulo operand

Comment: That question is about the first operand being negative, not the second.

Comment: @Barmar: but the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3883019/6451573) explains just what I commented "Unlike C or C++, Python's modulo operator (%) always return a number having the same sign as the denominator (divisor). Your expression yields 3 because". I wasn't going to answer just that (specially because I didn't know about that 5 minutes earlier :))

Comment: The answer is in the [third answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4432228/5987) to the question you linked, towards the end.