# Why is modulo of a negative number positive (-7 % 6 == 5)?

Tags: flutter, dart

Why is the following true?

```dart
print(-7 % 6 == 5);
```

This means that `-7 % 6` yields **`5`**, but I would **expect** to see `-1` (in JavaScript this is the case).

[Proof in DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/0cdcdc09bc7d177381cc51eeb7099375).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modulo behavior in Dart is different from the behavior in JavaScript, C, C++, and others. It shares its behavior with Python and about this topic there is a [question with great answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3883019/6509751).

#### Modulo will always yield a positive number in Dart.

---

Adding a bit to the [superb answer by @kennytm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3883019/6509751), the intuitive explanation for this is that it works analogous to positive factorisation (at least in Dart):

```
17 % 6 == 5          <=> -7 % 6 == 5
(2 * 6 + 5) % 6 == 5 <=> (-2 * 6 + 5) % 6 == 5
```

However, it could have easily been implemented differently, reasonably, but this is how it works in Dart.

A benefit of this is the following (quote from [the answer mentioned earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3883019/6509751)):

> It is chosen over the C behavior because a nonnegative result is often more useful. An example is to compute week days. If today is Tuesday (day #2), what is the week day *N* days before? In Python we can compute with
>
> ```py
> return (2 - N) % 7
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The `%` is actually a `remainder` operator in Java.  So it would return -1.

But a true modulo operator can have many remainders.  This is because
 a modulo operator means.

if  `b mod(m) == c`  Then there exists some integer `k` where `km = (b - c)`
which means that

(1)  `c = b - km` for any integer `k` is a valid answer.

so in your example,  `-7 % 6 = 5` works because  `k6 = (-7 -5) = -12 so k = -2`.

by (1) above, `c = -7 - k6` are all valid answers.

So for `-3 <= k <= 3`

`11, 5, -1, -7, -13, -19, -25` are all valid
`

To get the expected answer from your perspective, simply subtract 
 the modulus from the actual answer.  So `5 - 6 = -1`