# Javascript function rewritten in Java gives different results

Tags: javascript, java

There is this Javascript function that I'm trying to rewrite in Java:

```
function normalizeHash(encondindRound2) {
    if (encondindRound2 < 0) {
        encondindRound2 = (encondindRound2 & 0x7fffffff) + 0x80000000;
    }
    return encondindRound2 % 1E6;
}
```

My Java adaptation:

```
public long normalizeHash(long encondindRound2) {
        if (encondindRound2 < 0) {
            encondindRound2 = (((int) encondindRound2) & 0x7fffffff) + 0x80000000;
        }
        return (((int) encondindRound2) % 1_000_000);
    }
```

When I pass `-1954896768`, Javascript version returns `70528`, while Java returns `-896768`. I'm not sure why. The difference seems to start inside the if condition: in Javascript function after the if `encodingRound2 = 2340070528`, while in Java: `encodingRound2 = -1954896768`.

I made these repls to show it online:

*Javascript*: https://repl.it/repls/NumbGuiltyHack

*Java*: https://repl.it/repls/ClumsyQualifiedProblem

**EDIT**: Changing Java function to this

```
public long normalizeHash(long encondindRound2) {
        if (encondindRound2 < 0) {
            encondindRound2 = (encondindRound2 & 0x7fffffff) + 0x80000000;
        }
        return (encondindRound2 % 1_000_000);
    }
```

doesn't seem to affect the result - it's still `-896768`

Comment: Why are you casting `encondindRound2` to an `int` in the Java code?  Since it's defined as a `long`, you're going to potentially lose precision if you cast it to a narrower type.

Comment: @Jordan because - inside the if - there is a bitwise operation being performed on it. Javascript, although storing numbers as 64-bit floats, when doing bitwise, converts numbers to 32-bit integers. I had this issue with another piece of code before, when doing bitwise with Java's `long` gave different results, because of overflow.

Comment: Removing the `(int)` cast from the `return` line doesn't change the Java result, it remains `-896768`

Comment: It could be that the negative number has the same bits as the JavaScript number?

Comment: Ah, I found the issue.  When you tack on `... + 0x80000000`, Java converts the value to an int, because `0x80000000` is considered to be an int literal.  Change that number to `0x80000000L`.

Comment: @Jordan Wow, you are wizard! It worked! Please post your answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Java, 0x80000000 is outside the range of a 32bit int, so it wraps around to -2147483648.

In JavaScript, 0x80000000 is well inside the range of a 64bit double, so it remains 2147483648.

Obviously, adding `-2147483648` vs adding `2147483648` results in a very large discrepancy.

You can either use a `long` 0x80000000L in Java, or coerce your JS number into a 32bit int with `(0x80000000|0)`, depending on which you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You need to specify long values in doing the conversion.

```
    public static long normalizeHash(long encondindRound2) {
        if (encondindRound2 < 0) {
            encondindRound2 =  (encondindRound2 & 0x7fffffffL) + 0x80000000L;
        }

        return  (encondindRound2 % 1_000_000);
    }
```

But there is another issue you should be aware of.  Javascript treats `%` as a modulo operator where Java treats it as a simple remainder operator.  Check out this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59470362/why-is-modulo-of-a-negative-number-positive-7-6-5/59470831#59470831) for more information.