# VB.net output is different than python output, why is that?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Why the outputs of python and vb.net are different, the python result is the correct and expected output. Vb.net gives a wrong answer. how to rectify this? option strict on.

lm = -32617584047406127887053860912668548655625778953140441154984154756096705713545

Pcurve =  115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663

**Python**

```
tempreturn = lm % Pcurve
```

Python result: 83174505189910067536517124096019359197644205712500122884473429251812128958118

**VB.net**

```
Dim tempreturn As BigInteger = lm Mod Pcurve
```

VB.net Result: -32617584047406127887053860912668548655625778953140441154984154756096705713545

Comment: Just from curiosity I ran this calculation on octave online compiler (https://octave-online.net/), the answer is similar to VB.NET. ans =   -3.2618e+76

Comment: @jonathana: yes, I got the same answer from a online calculator. but try python code it gives a different answer and that is what I needed. I can't understand how come these languages give different answers.

Comment: But look, online python compilers gives the above answer different from vb.net and calculators  https://repl.it/repls/PitifulSqueakyCircles

Comment: I assume negative modulus is unusual in various programming languages, google search for "modulo negative numbers" returning interesting results. anyway I think you need to ask this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jonathana: It's still a relevant programming question, because different languages handle mod operators differently.  The math stack exchange may not know about those differences.

Comment: [What is the result of % in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/what-is-the-result-of-in-python)

Comment: *"I can't understand how come these languages give different answers"*. Given that that difference is explained in various places online, you just gave away that you did no research before posting, which is always a no-no.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The modulo operation on negative numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883004/the-modulo-operation-on-negative-numbers-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET, the modulus operator is not a true modulus; it's only a remainder calculation.  From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.op_modulus?view=netframework-4.8):

> Returns: The remainder that results from the division.

If you want a 'truer' mod function, try this:

```
Dim tempreturn as BigInteger = ((lm Mod Pcurve) + Pcurve) Mod Pcurve
```