# Question about the modulo operator (%) in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, modulo

I get that the modulo operator (`%`) is used to get the remainder of a division, so for example:

```
7 % 3 = 1
```

But, why does `1 % 60 = 1` and not `0.084`? (`1 - 0.016`)

Why does `-1 % 60 = 59`?

There must be something I don't understand about how this operator works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The modulo operation on negative numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883004/the-modulo-operation-on-negative-numbers-in-python)

Comment: In addition to the above, ```n % m = n for 0 < n < m```. In your example, the grade school representation of 1/60 would be 0R1 (zero remainder 1).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed.

1 divided by 60 is 0, the remainder is 1. Remainders are always Integers.

And the 59 is correct, because -1 // 60 is -1, and it must be true, that n == (n // divisor)*divisor + remainder, so -1 * 60 + 59 == -1

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the more general function `divmod`, which gives you both the quotient and the remainder:

```
divmod(n, m) == n // m, n % m
```

`divmod` obeys the following law (see `help(divmod)`) for all integers `n` and `m`:

```
q, r = divmod(n, m) <==> m*q + r == n
```

Further, `m` and `r` always have the same sign, and `0 <= abs(r) < abs(m)`. Neither of these is explicitly stated, but each follows from the definition of `//`.