# What does line 3 mean?

Tags: python-3.x, sys

```py
for i in range(21):
        sys.stdout.write('\r')
        sys.stdout.write("[%-20s] %a%%" % ('='*i, 5*i))
        time.sleep(0.25)
```

I need help understanding line 3. I would appreciate help. I know what this code does, but I don't know how. For example, I don't understand what the % does.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site. This question looks like an exact match, does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/1238306/3141234

Comment: The `%` is part of a "format specifier" - https://realpython.com/python-input-output/#the-string-modulo-operator -- `%-20s` says to "left-align a string 20 characters wide".

Comment: What does the letters mean in the code?

Comment: The realpython article or the stackoverflow?

Comment: The link in my comment. Here is a link to the Python ref. docs as well: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=printf#old-string-formatting Anyway, `%-20s` is read by `%/printf` as `%[flags=-][width=20][conversion=s]`, `%a` is read as `%[conversion=a]` and `%%` escapes the `%` so it has no meaning in the format (it will output a single `%`).