# how to create a list of strings consisting of strings and integers?

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, loops

that's a basic one but I'm stuck.

I want to create a list with combined strings and numbers like [df_22, df_23, ... df_30].

I have tried

```
def createList(r1, r2):
   return str(list(range(r1, r2+1)))
```

so it gives me a list of numbers:

```
In: mylist = createList(2, 30)
In: mylist
Out: '[22,23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]'
```

I am not sure how to add 'df_' to it because 'return df + str(list(range(r1, r2+1)))' gives an UFuncTypeError.

and

```
def createList(r1, r2):
   res = 'df_'
   return res + str(list(range(r1, r2+1)))

In: mylist = createList(22, 30)
In: mylist
Out: 'df_[22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]'
```

I need my list to be

mylist

Out: [df_22, df_21, ... df_30]

Comment: `mylist = [df_22, df_21, ... df_30]` is not valid Python (unless all of those df things have already been defined as variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what your title seems to describe:

```
def createList(r1, r2):
    return str(['df_%d'%x for x in range(r1, r2+1)])
```

Comment: thank you - my background is in finance and statistics not in programming. so yes I have amended my question after I have read your comments.

Comment: can you explain what '%x ' means in your solution?

Comment: [Old string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting) from the python docs. Also [What does % do to strings in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1238306/15497888)