# Django : What does "%" mean in self.success_messages % fiche.__dict__

Tags: django, dictionary, django-class-based-views

Since I've been leaning Python, I have often seen and used :

```
class FicheDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Fiche
    success_url = reverse_lazy('fiche-list')
    success_messages = "La Fiche %(ref_id)s a bien été supprimée"

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        fiche = self.get_object()
        messages.success(self.request, self.success_messages %
                         fiche.__dict__)
        return super(FicheDeleteView, self).delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Even if I see this mechanic's effects, I'm not really sure to understand.

Does it mean : I send to the "reverse-lazy" all the FICHE dict and in my **message.success** I retrieve the **fiche.ref_id** with **%(ref_id)s** ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238306/what-does-do-to-strings-in-python

Comment: Thanks @IainShelvington. I understand and already use this. But I wonder how the link is done between **%(ref_id)s** and **% fiche.__dict__**.
Does it automatically picks the **ref_id** key in the objects's dict ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` operator is an old string formatting placeholder, which lets you include variables in your string. So if you would want to include the variable `name` in your string then you could use the `%` operator as a placeholder.

```
name = 'world'
print('Hello, %s' % name)
>>> Hello, world
```

In your example, the `%` operator in `success_message` is taking a dictionary as variable and then accessing the value from the key `ref_id` in this dictionary.

```
success_messages = "La Fiche %(ref_id)s a bien été supprimée"
example_dict = {'key_1': 'value_1', 'ref_id': 'value_2'}
print(success_messages % example_dict)
>>> La Fiche value_2 a bien été supprimée
```

From Python >= 3.6 you can use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#3-string-interpolation-f-strings-python-36) which makes it more readable:

```
example_dict = {'key_1': 'value_1', 'ref_id': 'value_2'}
print(f"La Fiche {example_dict['ref_id']} a bien été supprimée")
>>> La Fiche value_2 a bien été supprimée
```

You can read more about python string formatting [here](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/)

Comment: OK. Now it's clearer. And I will use now the f-string. Thanks